# Protection of Django Rest Framework API with AllowAny permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ddos

I have a full-stack app and I am taking measures to protect the application from DDOS or bot attacks. All the sensitive data is protected by IsAuthenticated permission but there are still open APIs with public data with AllowAny permissions.

I have so far added throttling and limited the request rate to 100 for both anonymous and authenticated users and on the frontend side I've added Captcha to protect the server from mass user registration, what are more ways to protect the server?

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": ("accounts.authentication.Authentication",),
    # "EXCEPTION_HANDLER": "accounts.custom_exception_handler.custom_exception_handler"

    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/minute',
        'user': '100/minute'
    }
}
```

Comment: you can implenet JWT to authenticate the user, on authenticated users can access APIS

Comment: @TanveerAhmad I need protection for open api's, API that dont need authenticated users.

Comment: then JWT is enough but you have to use throttle as well